# Assigning subclass object to Superclass instance type is only for overriding concept?or we are doing this for something else also?

Tags: java, oop

Do you assign a subclass object to a Superclass instance type only for overriding? Or are we doing this for something else also?

Example:
Sub is subtype of Super and 
`Super s = new Sub();`

Please explain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When someone writes code like this, he/she is trying to follow a basic OO design principle which says -

> Program to an interface, not to a concrete implementation

I have explained this principle in [one of my blog posts](http://sayemdb.wordpress.com/2011/05/17/an-intro-to-design-pattern-2/). Look in the `Class Inheritance VS Interface Inheritance` section.

To summarize the post, when you use a reference of a parent type to refer to an instance of a sub-type, you get a lot of flexibility. For example, if you ever need to change your sub-type implementation in the future, you will be able to do that easily, without changing much of your code.

Consider the following method -

```
public void DoSomeStuff(Super s) {
    s.someMethod();
}
```

and a call to this method -

```
DoSomeStuff(new Sub());
```

now, if you ever need to change the logic inside `someMethod`, you can easily do it by declaring a new subtype of `Super`, say `NewSubType`, and changing the logic inside that implementation. In this way, you will never have to touch other existing code which utilizes that method. You will still be able to use your `DoSomeStuff` method in the following way -

```
DoSomeStuff(new NewSubType());
```

Had you declared the parameter of `DoSomeStuff` to be of `Sub`, you would then have to change its implementation too -

```
DoSomeStuff(NewSubType s) {
    s.someMethod();
}
```

and it may also chain/bubble to several other places.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but "overriding" is not the term i would use. Often, the reason to have a class hierarchy is not to **alter** the behavior of the super class, but to **implement** it. More often than not, the super class will either be an interface, and not a class, or be an abstract class following the template method pattern, where some methods are kept abstract and multiple subclasses implement those, but the general behavior is already fixed.

More concretely though, if we assign a subclass to a superclass instance variable like in your example, we want to limit the impact on our code in the case we exchange the subclass (we only need to edit one single line!)

Answer (score 0):

The characteristics of OO design that allows this (to handle object as instances of a common supertype) is called [polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).

One would assign a sub-type instance of to a supertype variable to handle all possible subtype classes in a uniform fashion, e.g. using methods declared (but possibly overriden) by the supertype class.

Related OO topics you might find interesting to read about:

- [abstract classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)
- [interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html)